How to adjustResize when the keyboard comes up in a Fragment that uses ComposeView
There is a BasicTextField in LazyColumn that can input about 30 characters. And there is a “Done” button at the very bottom. When you click on BasicTextField, the keyboard comes up so you can enter characters. However, the problem is that the area of ​​the screen visible to the user is reduced by the height of the keyboard, so the scroll area should also be reduced, but it does not.
The current Activity's manifest.xml is as follows:
<activity
    android:name:".MainActivity"
    android:windowSoftInpuMode="adjustResize">

The Fragment is as follows:
@Composable
fun ContentView() {
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        ... // 30 BasicTextFields

        Text(text = "Done")
    }
}

Even if the keyboard comes up, please help me see the Done button at the bottom when I scroll down!
